# How to get the alias name of a form field in my umbraco form

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using a umbraco form and i want to send the email to the input given on that field.

I want to set this alias name of the back-office umbraco form field to which an email has to be sent via workflow.

[image]

But whenever i try to send the email with the umbraco form field item using {fieldAliasName}, it is not working. But instead of alias name, when i pass the email address, it is sending an email.

I want to verify the alias name, how do i see it from my umbraco form.

[image]

Comment: I always open the form json file of the form (located in `\App_Plugins\UmbracoForms\Forms`). I agree that it's very weird there is no way to override it like we can with other properties in Umbraco

Comment: how to get to that folder from umbraco admin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to loop all existing form there

```
Umbraco.Forms.Data.Storage.FormStorage fs = new Umbraco.Forms.Data.Storage.FormStorage();

foreach (var f in fs.GetAllForms())
{
    Response.Write("Name:"+f.Name + ", Id:" + f.Id + "<br/>");
    foreach (var field in f.AllFields) {
        Response.Write("Alias:"+field.Alias + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

You will catch their alias name for sure..

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can do this.  To do what you want though, I suggest creating a custom Workflow.  Refer to the documentation here:

- [Umbraco Forms - Adding a Workflow Type](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Add-ons/UmbracoForms/Developer/Extending/Adding-a-Workflowtype)
- [Umbraco Forms - Adding a Type to the Provider Model](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Add-ons/UmbracoForms/Developer/Extending/Adding-a-Type)

Below is a sample Workflow you could base yours off that's a little simpler than the one mentioned above:

```
public class FormSelectSendEmail : SendEmail
{
    public FormSelectSendEmail()
    {
        Name = "Send Email to address in Form";
        Id = new Guid("9077B74A-1DC7-487A-AB9A-04E7048D1780");
        Description = "Send the result of the form to an email address typed into a form field";
    }

    [Setting("EmailField", 
        description = "Specify the field that email will be typed into.", 
        view = "~/App_Plugins/UmbracoFormExtensions/SettingTypes/fieldpicker.html")]
    public string EmailField
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public override List<Exception> ValidateSettings()
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>(base.ValidateSettings());
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.EmailField))
        {
            exceptions.Add(new Exception("'Email Field' has not been specified"));
        }
        return exceptions;
    }

    public override WorkflowExecutionStatus Execute(Record record, RecordEventArgs e)
    {
        var rf = record.RecordFields[new Guid(EmailField)];
        string email = rf.ValuesAsString(true);


        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        {
            // TODO: Send the Email

            return WorkflowExecutionStatus.Completed;
        }
        return WorkflowExecutionStatus.Cancelled;
    }

}
```

The `~/App_Plugins/UmbracoFormExtensions/SettingTypes/fieldpicker.html` doesn't exist in the above solution (yet) so here's some more code for you:

```js
angular.module("umbraco").controller("UmbracoFormExtensions.SettingTypes.FieldPickerController",
 function ($scope, $routeParams, pickerResource) {

     if (!$scope.setting.value) {
            $scope.setting.value = "";
     }

        pickerResource.getAllFields($routeParams.id).then(function (response) {
            $scope.fields = response.data;
        });

 });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="UmbracoFormExtensions.SettingTypes.FieldPickerController">
    <h5>Source Field</h5>
    <select ng-model="redirection.source" ng-options="field.id as field.value for field in fields">
        <option value="">Select a source field</option>
    </select>

</div>
```